# scandir points to disk root

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, scandir

I recently moved some display logic from raw output into a class and I've found rather strange behavior.

The old code:

```
$foo = scandir('\css');
```

Behavior: as expected, got me results from the \css folder in my web root.

However, I am making a themes class and so I wanted to roll all that into a function

```
class someClass {
    public function getCSS() {
       $foo = scandir('\css');
    }
}
```

That same code now generates an error, "The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) ". To test what was going on, I did the following:

```
print_r(scandir('/'));
```

Which gave me the directory listing for C:\, not my webroot.
What is going on? I am using the latest verion of WAMP, and PHP 5.4.3

Comment: Please show `getcwd` output from `getCSS` call

Comment: Sorry, but if you pass an absolute path to `scandir()` that has nothing to do with the DocumentRoot, since it has nothing to do with an http request. What you describe as the past behaviour cannot be true. What you describe as current behavior is the expected behavior.

Comment: getcwd returns my web root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I can't spell.
As @arkascha mentioned

```
$foo = scandir('\css');
```

should not be relative to my web root, the actual code was

```
$foo = scandir('css\');
```

which works as expected, obviously